# Any way to moniter a window thats minimized/inactive on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, python

I need something similar to [**LiveWindows**](http://www.autohotkey.com/community/viewtopic.php?t=11588) on Ubuntu that would allow me to have a little image of the window so I can monitor whats happening on that window even when I'm doing something else.

Or even some explanation as to how I could possibly implement something like this on my own. I have some experience using Python but I'm not very familiar with Linux so I have very little idea as to what tool/lib/etc to use to even begin something like this.

So far I've managed to only find how to take screenshots of the entire screen with Python which doesn't meet my needs as the window is inactive.

Does anybody have any ideas or direction on how I can accomplish this either on my own or through an already available program?

Answer (score 0):

I guess compiz can do it, i've not tried it myself, but worth looking into it

[Compiz Install](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2756/ubuntu_install_compiz_config_settings_manager_configure_desktop_effects/)